# Dicom Image error

Tags: python-3.x, dicom

I am trying to read a dicom image with the following code:

```
import dicom
from PIL import Image

Ima = dicom.read_file("MR000000.dcm")

f = Ima.pixel_array

sa = Image.fromarray(f)
sa.show()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1926, in fromarray
    mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
KeyError: ((1, 1), '<u2')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lala.py", line 8, in <module>
    sa = Image.fromarray(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1929, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

If anyone knows how to solve, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be as simple as your version of PIL does not support 16-bit image types. The numpy type string `"<u2"` is a "uint16", which is most likely the bit depth of you dicom image.  If you are using genuine PIL, you  might want to switch to [Pillow](https://python-pillow.github.io/)

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe that PIL (or Pillow) supports DICOM images because they are not mentioned on [their supported files list](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html).

I have used [pydicom](http://pydicom.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in the past, and it works quite well.

DICOM is a complicated standard.  Just reading the raw [pixel data (7FE0,0010)](http://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/ct-image/image-pixel/7fe00010) is usually not enough.  For example, you may want to apply the [slope (0028,1053)](http://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/ct-image/ct-image/00281053) and [intercept (0028,1052)](http://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/ct-image/ct-image/00281052) values to the raw pixel data in order to arrive at floating point values with the proper units and offset.